# Numpy and += effect

Tags: python, numpy

Something I don't understand with Python 3.3.3 and NumPy:

```
from numpy import *
x1 = zeros(1)
x2 = x1
x1+=1
```

It turns out, this makes both the x1 and x2 variables [1], which I don't understand. If you instead do x1=x1+1, then I get x1 as [1] and x2 as [0], which is what I was after.

Comment: Just as a general comment, while the behavior you're seeing isn't exactly `numpy`-specific, it is much more common to use "in-place" operators (e.g. `+=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc) on numpy arrays than on many other python objects.  This is because something like `x = x + 1` uses twice the memory of `x += 1`.  If `x` is a large array, it can be very important to have tight control over memory usage.  Furthermore, `x = x + 1.0` will cause `x` to become a floating point array if it wasn't already, while `x += 1.0` will keep the original dtype of `x`. (That last part is numpy-specific.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x2 = x1` makes both variables `x2` and `x1` refer to the same object.

`x1+=1` changes the object underlying the reference `x1` (and `x2`).

Conversely, if you did `x1=x1+1` then you create a *new* object (the result of `x1+1`) and assign the result to `x1` only, while `x2` remains unchanged and refers to the original object.

This is unrelated to NumPy, by the way – it’s a consequence of the general way references work.

Comment: Why doesn't this work the same way with a regular python variable then?

Comment: @cpc333 - Because integers in python are immutable. They can't be changed.  Therefore, `x = 1; y = x; y += 1` causes a copy of `y` to be made before the addition and then reassigns it to `y`.  However, numpy arrays are mutable. They can be changed. Therefore, `+=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc modify the numpy array in-place.

Comment: @cpc333 It totally does, where the operators are defined appropriately (= on mutable types).

Comment: @cpc333. Actually it depends on the object, strings, integers, floats and tuples are exceptions to the rule most python objects do behave this way. try with lists for example.

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `__iadd__` (if any).  Mutable types generally try to manipulate the item in place.  Immutable types generally don't define `__iadd__` at all, and the operator `+=` then falls back on `__add__`, so a new object is created (and you see the `id` change when `+=` is used)

Comment: I say "generally" because this is not a hard and fast rule..  `collections.Counter`, for example, is a mutable type but it doesn't modify `self` when `+=` was used.